# Nginx / PHP FPM graceful stop (SIGQUIT): not so graceful

Tags: php, nginx

Running nginx 1.9.* / PHP 7.0.* (but exact same behavior in 5.6.* also)

Attempting to gracefully stop a PHP-FPM / nginx combo for node shutdown during maintenance. To do this, I'm sending the SIGQUIT to php-fpm, which **should** provide a graceful shutdown.

To test this, I made a dumb script

```
<?php sleep(5); echo 'done';
```

Tested locally with the following curl

```
curl -I x.x.x.x:8080
```

Which normally produces the output:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Tue, 12 Apr 2016 04:48:00 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Connection: close
```

Desired: in the middle of any in-flight request, when a graceful shutdown is requested, the current requests should finish, but any additional requests should fail.

Unfortunately, when I try to trigger this behavior, by sending a SIGQUIT (http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man8/php5-fpm.8.html) to the PHP-FPM master process:

```
kill -s SIGQUIT $FPMPID
```

The connection **immediately** drops, resulting in an ngnix 502

```
HTTP/1.1 502 Bad Gateway
Server: nginx
Date: Tue, 12 Apr 2016 04:48:07 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 166
Connection: close
```

Any advice? I would love to make this piece of the system as seamless as possible. Thanks!

Comment: Attached link is fairly dead (503), process signals summarized here: https://forum.nginx.org/read.php?3,3485,template=head%3F%3F.

Comment: Yep. https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=41593 and, for me even important-er, **https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=60961**. I don't know how exactly (and if) they're related, but PHP-FPM unfortunately has its little annoyances.

Comment: I can suggest little workaround to you. It's not fix php-fpm, but help to answer 200 :) All you need is to set up `upstream` in nginx config with 2-3 backends (it can be same php-fpm pool few times). So, if one of requests fail, nginx will try to request backend again.

Answer (score 4):

After struggling with this same situation for a while, I believe I've found the magical config setting to make child processes finish handling requests before dying.

http://php.net/manual/en/install.fpm.configuration.php#process-control-timeout

> **process_control_timeout**
>
> Time limit for child processes to wait for a reaction on signals from master

Basically, by setting this to something like `10s`, the child process will wait that long, while handling existing requests before quitting.

Unfortunately, it seems that the `php-fpm` master process exits immediately, so, inspired by the code [here](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/1c295d4a9ac78fcc2f77d6695987598bb7abcb83/sapi/fpm/init.d.php-fpm.in), I wrote a wrapper script:

```
#!/bin/bash

PHP_FPM_PID='/php-fpm.pid'

wait_for_pid () {
    try=0

    while test $try -lt 35 ; do
        if [ ! -f "$1" ] ; then
            try=''
            break
        fi

        echo -n .
        try=`expr $try + 1`
        sleep 1
    done
}

function clean_up {

    echo "Killing $(cat $PHP_FPM_PID)"

    kill -QUIT `cat $PHP_FPM_PID`
    wait_for_pid $PHP_FPM_PID

    echo "Done!"

    exit 0
}

trap clean_up EXIT

nohup php-fpm --daemonize --pid $PHP_FPM_PID 2>&1 &

while true; do sleep 1; done
# ^ do nothing forever
```

which waits 35 seconds or until that pid file has been removed (presumably by one of the child processes? I'm still unclear on *how* it's removed).

Regardless, this wrapper script works well as the `CMD` for our `php-fpm` docker container that we're running with Kubernetes.

Comment: Seems like a useful setting, but does this mean that it *always* waits X seconds before responding? I've sort of reversed this process for my docker container (https://github.com/bryanlatten/docker-php), where instead of immediately signaling fpm to gracefully shut down, I gracefully shut down its forward nginx proxy - which will be graceful and wait for connections to complete. In theory, with no connections coming in, and outgoing connections waiting for close, PHP can then terminate like an elephant and nothing in flight should be affected. Does this make sense?

Comment: Absolutely, I think using nginx as a graceful-shutdown-proxy here is the right solution. It won't work for us unfortunately, but I think that's the way to go in the future.

Comment: "Unfortunately, it seems that the php-fpm master process exits immediately"


What nonsense is this. Master process cannot be killed wihout children processes with it