# PHP-FPM (7.4.2) doesn't stop gracefully?

Tags: php, linux

During updating, we want to stop php-fpm and wait for all running scripts to be finished before we make any file changes.

We found out that we needed to set process_control_timeout, so we placed "process_control_timeout = 36000s" in "/etc/php/7.4/fpm/pool.d/zz-00-overrides.ini" (and we restarted php-fpm).

Then we created a test script to test it out. Our test script creates a file, then 30 seconds later, it creates another file. The script:

```
$id = random_int(10000, 99999);
file_put_contents(__DIR__ . '/' . $id . '-start', '');
sleep(30);
file_put_contents(__DIR__ . '/' . $id . '-end', '');
```

When we run the script normally (browser -> nginx -> php-fpm), it creates the 1st file, 30 seconds later it creates the 2nd file.

When we run the script, wait a few seconds, and then try to stop it (run the same way as before: browser -> nginx -> php-fpm) (stopped by: "service php7.4-fpm stop"), it will create the 1st file, then the service stop command is run which only takes 2-3 seconds, then the browser says "502 Bad Gateway", and then the 2nd file is never created.

It doesn't gracefully stop. The desired outcome for us is that "service php7.4-fpm stop" waits for all the scripts to be done, and then stops, instead of it killing off any running scripts the way it is doing now in order to forcefully stop.

Are we missing something, are we doing something wrong? Is it a bug somewhere somehow? Any help would be really appreciated.

- Debian 10 (Linux 4.19.0-6-cloud-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.67-2+deb10u2 (2019-11-11) x86_64 GNU/Linux)
- PHP 7.4.2
- Nginx 1.14.2

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Nginx / PHP FPM graceful stop (SIGQUIT): not so graceful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36564074/nginx-php-fpm-graceful-stop-sigquit-not-so-graceful)

Comment: @ArSeN No sadly not. We stumbled upon it before, it's where we got the "process_control_timeout" info from. Weirdly enough it just ignores it. We've tried setting it to 35, 35s, 1h, etc as well, but nothing works. It will immediately (within 2-3 seconds) stop, and it will kill the running scripts while doing so.

Comment: Have you had a look on whether sending a signal (rather than stopping the service) as described in the linked post does the trick? I am not sure but my guess is service stopping sends the "wrong" signal

Comment: @ArSeN Hey, doing `kill -QUIT \`cat /run/php/php7.4-fpm.pid\`` works. It interrupts sleeps, but even when we do a while loop that will take 30 seconds, it will wait for it as well. So the best solution is to run that quit command, then in bash, wait for the pid file to be removed.

Comment: So basically this is a duplicate after all? ;)

Comment: @ArSeN I suppose you're right. I thought the answer on that page was something unrelated, but it turns out it was actually the right answer, it was just a bit of a mess / confusing, as it provides an entire script, and it doesn't put emphasis on the fact that `service php7.4-fpm stop` does **not** take the `process_control_timeout` value into account, while `kill -QUIT $(cat /run/php/php7.4-fpm.pid)` does. I think that's the most important part of understanding why it didn't work and knowing what the solution to this is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running `kill -QUIT $(cat /run/php/php7.4-fpm.pid)` does take the `process_control_timeout` config in account. It will cause the PHP-FPM process to stop as soon as all the scripts have finished their execution. At that point the PID will be removed. So, in order to make it work:

1. run `$(kill -QUIT $(cat /run/php/php7.4-fpm.pid))`
2. in a loop, check if `/run/php/php7.4-fpm.pid` still exists, if not, break the loop.